# @JsonPropertyOrder and fields from the super class

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following class hierarchy:
**EDIT**

```
public abstract class A implements Content {
    private long id;
    ....
}

@JsonPropertyOrder({"id"})
public class B extends A{
    private String oderField;
...
}

public interface Content{
   //Some get methods
}

@JsonPropertyOrder({"c"})
public class DefaultContent{
   private Content c;
   private String anotherProperty;
}
```

By serializing a `B` object, the first field I see in the JSON is `oderField`, and I would like to change it, and to get `id` in the first place.

**Serialization**:

```
public class Serializer{
private Gson gson;
public Serializer(){
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS");
        gson = gsonBuilder.create();
        gsonParser = new JsonParser();
}

public String serializeMessage(DefaultContent messageToSerialize) {
        return gson.toJson(messageToSerialize);
    }
}
```

I has used `@JsonPropertyOrder`, but it seems to order the properties in the same class, not taking into account the super class. Has anybody some idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean you tried `@JsonPropertyOrder({"id", "oderField"})` on class B, and it still did not work?

Comment: Could you show us, how you serialize your class?

Comment: I have edited my question with all the implementation details

Comment: Instead of having to repeat all the fields in all (concrete) classes in a type hierarchy with `@JsonPropertyOrder`, duplication can at least be eliminated by using `@JsonProperty( index = [...] )` instead, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49688852/jackson-property-order-and-inheritance/70165014#70165014. I suppose this can get messy if fields from different hierarchy levels should be interleaved, but should be fine in general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem comes from the way annotations are handled: annotations in sub-class will override ones in sub-class. There is no way to mix those; so what you need to do to make things work is to replicate settings in sub-class. This is unfortunate, but that's how annotation handling works in Jackson.

Comment: replicate in subclass works