# Jackson: Property Order and Inheritance

Tags: java, json, jackson

What is the best practice to change the property order in a subclasse during the serialization process with Jackson?

Assuming the following simplified scenario:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "p1", "p2" })
class animal {
    int p1;
    int p2;
}

@JsonPropertyOrder({ "p3", "p1", "p2" })
class cat extends animal{
    int p3;
}
```

Is this possible? Does the subclass `@JsonPropertyOrder` overrides the partent class definition? Or can I add the `"p3"` in the partent annotation to save redundance? The jackson documentation is very short on this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@JsonPropertyOrder can be used to give specific order in which the details of the data expected in the output json, so using this annotation changing the order is possible.

@JsonPropertyOrder is an annotation which can be used at class level. It takes the properties as a `list of fields - these fields can be either in the parent class or in the child class` that defines the order in which fields will appear in the string resulting from the object JSON serialization.

Reference:

[Jackson JSON using @JsonPropertyOrder annotation to define properties serialization order](http://www.davismol.net/2016/10/24/jackson-json-using-jsonpropertyorder-annotation-to-define-properties-serialization-order/)

Comment: Your link only uses the annotation on the subclass. Thus, it doesn't "poves" the `cat` annotation will override the `animal` on. However, regarding the second part of my question, can I add the `"p3"` in the base class to not keep both annotations in sync, if I change the base class?

Comment: You can add p3 in the base class, by doing so the order which is given in the base class will be used when the json is produced, however if you need to modify the order given in the base class, you can use the annotation @JsonPropertyOrder in your child class.

Answer (score 4):

As per this [documentation](https://tedblob.com/jackson-serialization-order/), you can use @JsonProperty(index) to avoid redundant code.

```
class animal {
    @JsonProperty(index=2)
    int p1;
    @JsonProperty(index=3)
    int p2;
}

class cat extends animal{
    @JsonProperty(index=1)
    int p3;
}
```

Comment: A good practice is to set the index in a magnitude of 10 or 100. i.e. 2 => 20 or 200. The reason is this is maintanance.  If there comes a new prop that you want inbetween you have to change  all  the higher indexes otherwise