# How can I reorder the elements of a map in java?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I am making a query to a Postgresql database using java (spring-boot), but when storing the data in a map the order of the elements is not conversing, and it is very important that they have the same order to be able to generate a report.

This is the query that returns the information as a json

```
@Query(value = "select f.entity_id as \"NIT\", f.subpoena_number as \"Número Comparendo\", f.plate as \"Placa\", f.code as \"Código Infracción\", f.infringement_date \"Fecha Infracción\", f.amount as \"Valor\", f.city as \"Ciudad\", f.address as \"Dirección\", f.upload_date as \"Fecha del cargue\", f.notification_status as \"Estado Notificación\", f.process_status as \"Estado Proceso\", f.source_data as \"Origen\", case when f.paying = true then 'PAGADO' else 'SIN PAGAR' end as \"Estado Pago\", f.payment_date as \"Fecha Pago\" from renting.fine f inner join renting.company c on c.nit = f.entity_id and c.companyparent_id = f.companyparent inner join renting.notification n on f.id = n.fine_id where f.companyparent = :companyParent and f.upload_date > :lastUpdate and f.upload_date < :endUpdate ", nativeQuery = true)
List<Map<String , Object>> generateComparingReport(@Param("lastUpdate") LocalDateTime lastUpdate,
                               @Param("endUpdate") LocalDateTime endUpdate,
                                @Param("companyParent") String companyParent);
```

How can I order the elements as I need them while preserving the json data type? I tell you that if I use a List<String[]> it respects the order, but even so I require that it be a json

Comment: You need to use a sorted map. But in general the order of keys in a JSON value has no meaning. It's a bug waiting to happen if you rely on that order

Comment: You can try to create a Pojo for the response and annotate the fields with JsonProperty ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72993361/spring-boot-customize-order-of-properties-in-response )

Comment: I don't know if this is useful for you or not, but Java offers a [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)